# UFW -- How To Open Port 8080

Tags: firewall, port, ufw

I thought I had allowed connections to http-alt (8080) using ufw. My reasoning for thinking this is because:

```
gerrit2@localhost:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

and

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere    

...

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere    

...

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt
```

However, when I go to see if that port is open with nmap I get the following:

```
[mehoggan@localhost ~]$ nmap -p 8080 matthewh.me

Starting Nmap 6.45 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-07-07 20:00 PDT
Nmap scan report for matthewh.me (50.116.18.212)
Host is up (0.050s latency).
rDNS record for 50.116.18.212: li418-212.members.linode.com
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8080/tcp closed http-proxy
```

What do I need to do to open that port up to the outside world using Ubuntu's 14.04 ufw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did open your firewall correctly. In order to "open" the port, you need to actually have a service running that listens on port 8080.

Comment: I am trying to start gerrit code review to listen on that port, but it keeps failing. So I thought I had to open the port first for the service to listen on.

Comment: Congratulations, you've stumbled into [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912).